# How to change all the property names of a json object

Tags: javascript, json, replace

I would like to change all the property names of a json object

```
const obj = {
  "country": "Value1",
  "area": "value2",
  "color_flag": "value3"
}

const newKeys = ["pays", "Superficie", "Couleur de drapeau"]

// I would like to have something like this : 

obj = {
  "pays": "Value1",
  "superficie": "Value2",
  "couleur_drapeau": "Value3"
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: How would you which old key to map to which of the new keys? Objects are not ordered.

Comment: That would be a different property. After assignment `obj.pays = obj.country; delete obj.country;`, if those are Primitive Values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can clone your object using new keys, but you need to provide a map for your new keys like this:

```
const newKeys = {
  "country": "pays",
  "area": "superficie",
  "color_flag": "couleur_drapeau"
}
```

Simply on the left put the original key, and on the right put the new one that in your case is the translation to french.

Then you need to loop over all keys of your original object and copy each value to the new object with the new key

```
const renamedObj = {}
for(let key in obj){
  const newKey = newKeys[key]
  renamedObj[newKey] = obj[key]
}
```

Final code should be like this:

```
const obj = {
  "country": "Value1",
  "area": "value2",
  "color_flag": "value3"
}

const newKeys = { // Keys map
  "country": "pays",
  "area": "superficie",
  "color_flag": "couleur_drapeau"
}

const renamedObj = {}
for(let key in obj){
  const newKey = newKeys[key]
  renamedObj[newKey] = obj[key]
}
```

`renamedObj` should look like this:

```
renamedObj = {
  "pays": "Value1",
  "superficie": "Value2",
  "couleur_drapeau": "Value3"
}
```

Comment: If `newKeys` can contain a subset of keys of `obj` use `renamedObj[newKey || key] = obj[key]` instead. This uses the old key if it can't find a truthy value for the new key. Otherwise a fine answer.